# Python testing a call to a class's method instantiated as a varable in another class

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have a class `A`, which receives config for another class B in its constructor. `A` then creates a variable out of `B` by using this config and creating an instance of class `B`.
Later in the code it calls this variable as `self.b.do_somthing()`.

How can I make sure this method call is actually called with mock/patch? Below I post a super simple dummy code doing a similar thing. I want to test that `perform()` actually called `sing_a_song()`

**Please pay attention to the comments in the code**

`my_app.py`

```
class Sing:
    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.songs = {
            "almost home": """
                Almost home
                Brother, it won't be long
                Soon all your burdens will be gone
                With all your strength""",
            "smooth criminal": """
                Annie, are you okay?
                So, Annie, are you okay? Are you okay, Annie?
            """
        }
        self.config = config

    def sing_a_song(self, song_name):
        return self.songs.get(song_name.lower())


class Singer:
    def __init__(self, song_to_sing):
        self.song_to_sing = song_to_sing
        self.sing = Sing(**some_config_that_doesnt_matter)  # <-- this part is the culprit

    def perform(self):
        if self.song_to_sing.lower() == "smooth criminal":
            self.sing.sing_a_song(self.song_to_sing)   # <-- and it's called here
        else:
            return "I don't know this song, not gonna perform."
```

And the test (which doesn't work)

`test.py`

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_app import Singer


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_app.Sing", autospec=True)
    def test_download(self, sing_mock):
        melissa = Singer("smooth criminal")
        melissa.perform()

        sing_mock.assert_called()  # <-- works  (because of the call inside the constructor or bc of the call inside perform() ???
        sing_mock.sing_a_song.assert_called()   # <-- returns AssertionError: Expected 'sing_a_song' to have been called. 
        sing_mock.assert_called_with("smooth criminal")   # <-- returns AssertionError: Expected call: Sing('smooth criminal') ... Actual call: Sing()


        # If I do the following, the test passes, BUT if i after that REMOVE the actual
        # call to self.sing.sing_a_song(self.song_to_sing), it still passes ??!?!!?
        sing_mock.sing_a_song("smooth criminal")
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Also.. i realize that the call is actually made to the class and not the object's method as if the method is static, but it's not defined as such and therefore I somehow need to fix this.

So.. what am I doing wrong, please help. I am still new the mocking and patching and I am quite confused no matter how many articles I read.

Comment: You are are checking the calls on the class instead of the instance. To get the calls on the instance, you need `sing_mock.return_value.sing_a_song.assert_called_with("smooth criminal")`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yes i relize that and in fact just modified the description with this, but i had no idea how to fix it. Thank you for your comment! Please add it as an answer and I will mark as solved :) Thank you very much! I'm still a bit confused of the chaining after the `return_value` part, wasn't aware it's possible to do it this way. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are mocking a class, and want to check method calls on that class, you have to check them on the instance of the class. You get the class instance of a mock using `return_value` on the mock (which generally gives you the result of the call operator, which in the case of a class is the class instantiation). Note that instantiating a specific class mock will always give you the same "instance" (e.g another mock).

So in your case, the following will work:

```py
class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_app.Sing", autospec=True)
    def test_download(self, sing_mock):
        melissa = Singer("smooth criminal")
        melissa.perform()

        sing_mock.assert_called()  # this asserts that the class has been instantiated
        sing_mock_instance = sing_mock.return_value  # split off for readability
        sing_mock_instance.sing_a_song.assert_called()
        sing_mock_instance.sing_a_song.assert_called_with("smooth criminal")
```

Comment: Super useful and very informative, somehow I didn't realize this by reading the articles around or SO here where people usually discuss the mock of the class but not the instance (or i've missed it). Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me! Just a side note to make is, if the module that you'd like to mock is not in the same script as your main module, patch that module from the place it got imported and used. For example, in this case, if Sing was in another script sing.py, don't patch it from sing.py, patch it from my_app instead

Answer (score 2):

The other approach works for mocking the whole class `Sing`. However, depending on what you want to test exactly, you may want to mock only the specific method:

```py
class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('my_app.Sing.sing_a_song')
    def test_download(self, sing_a_song_mock):
        melissa = Singer('smooth criminal')
        melissa.perform()

        sing_a_song_mock.assert_called()  # this works
        sing_a_song_mock.assert_called_with('smooth criminal')  # works, too
```

For instance, this might be useful in some cases when you already know that you tested the instantiation of the class in other tests, and you now just want to test the exact call of the class method in the current test.